# Performance Testing Tool for a REST Web API

Tags: json, rest, jenkins, scalability, performance-testing

I'm looking for an OpenSource performance testing tool for our REST API.
The server (writen in CakePHP) provides functions which deliveres xml / json (both is possible) for a mobile application. Here are some information:

- REST API
- Session is saved in Cookies
- MySQL
- Jenkin Integration is necessary
- XML (JSON) validation is necessary
- dynamic variables (e.g. ids) are necessary
- scalability over some servers is necessary

I thought jMeter, soapUI or Visual Studio are good solutions?

Comment: Visual Studio is not open source.

Comment: oh, yeah, sorry, I forgot but we've got a licence (from university) ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion [Gatling](https://github.com/gatling/gatling) is the tool you need :

- There is a plugin for Jenkins : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gatling+Plugin
- Support XML and JSON of course and MySQL monitoring
- Dynamics variables
- Very scalable (many plugins)